# swift - pre-download videos like the Instagram app

Tags: ios, swift, video, streaming, instagram

Currently, I have a video feed with streaming video URLs from a video hosting service. I want to play the videos as soon as a cell appears on the screen but with this approach is not possible because we always have buffering time.

I was checking this behavior on Instagram (iOS) and if we open it and wait for few to load the feed and quickly switch to airplane mode, we can see all video posts have a few seconds of each video pre-downloaded. If we wait on a video it's frozen after this pre-downloaded part is played. The Instagram app is fetching their feed and start pre-downloading all their videos to be able to start as soon as a cell appears on the screen.

I was checking some ideas around like use the AVQueuePlayer or download little % of the video, but there isn't much info about this...Is this "Instagram approach" possible or too hard to do?

Comment: Hi @xvicient. Maybe this library work. -> https://github.com/neekeetab/CachingPlayerItem

Comment: I think CachingPlayerItem could be a good solution. The pod provides the ability to download a video and start playing it without stop the download. Maybe a limitation will be managing the downloads to avoid memory issues.

Comment: Hi again @xvicient, I'll happy if it works.

Comment: It seems that it works but I'm facing some issues with streaming videos https://github.com/neekeetab/CachingPlayerItem/issues/23

Comment: @xvicient hi! How did you solve it back then?

Answer (score 0):

Not that hard to do but some libraries are already available . You can use following simple library to make it work

[AGVideoPlayerView](https://github.com/AG-iOS/AGVideoPlayerView)

Comment: The example is showing a buffering spinner and waiting for the video...